# Get the name of variable function was assigned to

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to return the name of the variable that a function is assigned to.

I have included an example below. The end result is I would like `modelPerson.title()` to return the variable name `title`.

For example, I have the following code:

**Defining some base model types**

```
var types = {
    string: function() {
        return function() {
            return "I want this to return 'title'";
        }
    }
};
```

**Using the model types**

```
var modelPerson = {
    title: types.string(),
    firstName: types.string(),
    surname: types.string(),
    position: types.string()
};
```

**Trying to return the title**

```
console.log(modelPerson.title());
```

Sorry if this is a little unclear. I have included a JSFiddle if it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/4f6VE/

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: what isn't working properly?

Comment: Hi Mark. I would like the function `string()` to return the name of the variable it was assigned to. In this case it should return a string `title`

Comment: ok, nevermind, i see what you're trying to do

Comment: Yeah, that returns the string `"I want this to return 'title'"`. What exactly isn't working as expected?

Comment: I get it. Sort of have the value (in this case the function) know which key it is assigned to? I'm not sure there's a way to figure that out. I'm interested in the solution anyone finds.

Comment: im not sure if this is possible, but very good question!

Comment: would you be willing to give it a little slack? For example, instead of this, would you be ok doing this: `modelPerson.data.title`? and just accessing the property, not executing a function?

Comment: Yeah Mark, well I want to be able to assign functions on the `title` and I think I know what you're getting at. In the real-life scenario I'm using getters/setters, so this is more of a 'can it be done' question.

Comment: the only way to achive that sort of refection is to iterate the values in modelPerson and when arguments.callee == modelPerson[k], alert(k).

Comment: It'd be easy to do some post processing to make it work after it had already been created

Answer (score 7):

That's actually possible, but involves some v8 specific stuff:

```
var types = {
    string: function() {
        return function() {
          var obj = {};
          var prepare = Error.prepareStackTrace;
          Error.prepareStackTrace = function (_, stack) {
            return stack
          }

          Error.captureStackTrace(obj)

          var method = obj.stack[0].getMethodName();

          Error.prepareStackTrace = prepare;

          return method;
        }
    }
};

var modelPerson = {
    title: types.string(),
    firstName: types.string(),
    surname: types.string(),
    position: types.string()
};

console.log(modelPerson.title());
console.log(modelPerson.firstName());
```

but you probably should use something less insane

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what is this for, but

```
var modelPerson = {
 title : function title(){ return arguments.callee.name; },
 firstName : function firstName(){ return arguments.callee.name; },
 surname : function surname(){ return arguments.callee.name; },
 position : function position(){ return arguments.callee.name; },
}
```

should do what you say.

**EDIT**

Banzaaai~ !

```
var types = {
 string: function(){
  eval('var x = function '+arguments.callee.caller.name+'(){var x = function(){return arguments.callee.caller.name;}; return x();}');
  return x(); 
 }
};
var modelPerson = {
 title: function title(){ return types.string(); },
 firstName: function firstName(){ return types.string(); },
 surname: function surname(){ return types.string(); },
 position: function position(){ return types.string(); }
};
```

**SRSLY THOUGH**

```
var types = {
 string: function(x){
  return function(){ return x; }
 }
};
var modelPerson = {
 title: types.string('title'),
 firstName: types.string('firstName'),
 surname: types.string('surname'),
 position: types.string('position')
};
```

Comment: I think he/she wants it to work for all possible functions, not just these

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm more curious if the `string` function can return this, as it is buried two layers deep. But nice attempt :)

Comment: Here you go, but it's completely hideous.

Comment: lol nice try mate. You know, if we could get rid of the eval I might sleep well at night. Definitely the closest thing to a solution, but agree it's hideous with that eval :P

Comment: Last try, I'm out of ideas. This is clean but not sure about you enjoying it.

Comment: Yeah that was kinda the conclusion I ended up on Jiri. If I wanted to this this, I would have to add a parameter to the function. One up for the effort mate. Hopefully your response will help someone :)

Comment: It was fun.^^ Btw - you could make a function addAttr(name) that would add those 4 attributes to modelPerson with correct return values. You would make an empty modelPerson = {}; then Object.prototype.addAttr = function(name){this[name] = function(){ return name; } }; then modelPerson.addAttr('title');

Comment: Not sure whether I should up- or downvote such abnomination… Please explicitly discourage from using deprecated `.callee` and non-standard `.name` :-)

Comment: This is a non-standard question though, isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to return the name of the variable that a function is assigned to

You can't, not reliably. Several variables or properties can reference the same object, and some objects exists without ever being assigned to a variable (such as function expressions without a name that are called immediately).

Comment: that's true in an all-encompassing universal sense, but incorrect in the limited scenario outlined by the OP that's without those potential complications. That said, I do think that there are better ways to achieve this kind of reflection, even if it means some hard/double coding...

Answer (score 0):

> The end result is I would like modelPerson.title() to return the variable name title.

Then use something like this:

```
function define(obj, name) {
    obj[name] = function() {
        return name;
    };
}

var modelPerson = {};
define(modelPerson, "title");
define(modelPerson, "firstName");
define(modelPerson, "surname");
define(modelPerson, "position");
//                  … - a loop maybe?
```

```
> console.log(modelPerson.title());
"title"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a method that can work in strict mode (without deprecated arguments.callee or proprietary arguments.callee.caller properties), using your code with minimal re-factoring and no hard-coded names:

```
var types={
    string: function types(){       
           return function me() { 
               for(var it in this){
                    if(me==this[it]) return it;
               }
        };
    }
};


var modelPerson = {
    title: types.string(),
    firstName: types.string(),
    surname: types.string(),
    position: types.string()
};


alert( modelPerson.title() ); // shows: "title"
alert( modelPerson.surname() ); // shows: "surname"
```

Comment: That only works where a function is called as a method of an object and *this* references that objetct. It will not work for a case in a function execution context like `(function(){var a = modelPerson.title; a();}())` and not in strict mode if *this* is not set to the right object.

Comment: @RobG: that's true, but this works within the pattern requested by the OP.

Comment: @dandavis: Sorry, You posted your answer, while I typed mine, so I didn't see it. I respect that you were faster, so I deleted my answer, and gave yours a +1.

Comment: @dandavis—the OP asks about variables, but the example uses object properties. :-/